# How to read CSV in Hazelcast jet in List<Map> or JsonArray format?

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-jet

As I am new to hazelcast am I trying few thing but not getting result as I accepted, please help me out.
Here is my below code which I am trying but not getting success.

```
 BatchSource<List> companyListBatchSource = FileSources.files("directory")
                .glob("name.csv")
                .format(FileFormat.csv(List.class))
                .build();

            pipeline.readFrom(companyListBatchSource)
                .writeTo(Sinks.list("mapName"));
```

Let me know how can we read it in List<Map<String, Object>> or JsonArray?

Comment: Can you please share a sample data line from the CSV file? The files source reads the file line-by-line, converting the line to the structured Jet record using the file format provided. This record can be stored to the list as-is, or transformed.

Comment: @VladoSchreiner, Sorry I didn't get your point, you can take any csv file with any number of columns or rows to test it. Header are dynamic

Comment: I misunderstood your question, please ignore my comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a list of field-names if you don't want to convert the values to a dedicated record, in that case you'll get a `String[]` as a record.

```
List<String> fieldNames = new ArrayList<>();
fieldNames.add("foo");
fieldNames.add("bar");
BatchSource<String[]> source = FileSources.files("directory")
    .glob("file.csv")
    .format(FileFormat.csv(fieldNames))
    .build();
```

And if you don't know the fields beforehand, you can pass `null` as the list of field-names.

You can also create a custom file source like below

```
    BatchSource<Map<String, String>> source = Sources.filesBuilder("directory")
            .glob("file.csv")
            .build(path -> {
                Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path);
                String[][] headers = new String[1][];
                return lines.filter(line -> {
                    if (headers[0] == null) {
                        headers[0] = line.split(",");
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }).map(line -> {
                    String[] values = line.split(",");
                    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < headers[0].length; i++) {
                        String header = headers[0][i];
                        String value = values[i];
                        map.put(header, value);
                    }
                    return map;
                });
            });
```

Comment: but fields name are not fix, as csv file is dynamic, and I don't want String[], I required List<Map> or JsonArray

Comment: There is no OOTB way to achieve that, I've updated my answer with a custom file source.